# trying to merge multi array

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to merge multi array to have the following format, but I don't know what to do next.

```psh
$ComputerDisabled = Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -ComputersOnly |
                    Select-Object name | Sort-Object
$ComputerDisabled | ForEach-Object {
  $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerDisabled -Value $_.Name
}
$UserDisabled = Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly |
                Select-Object Name | Sort-Object
$UserDisabled | ForEach-Object {
  $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name UserDisabled -Value $_.Name
} 
$ComputerDisabled | select ComputerDisabled
$UserDisabled | select UserDisabled | more
```

My ultimate goal is to export this out to a CSV files:

```
ComputerDisabled    UserDisabled            
----------------    ------------
computer            user5
computer            user8
```

Comment: Is it a definitive requirement of yours to have disabled user accounts and disabled computer accounts side by side in your csv? Usually a table is read row by row, so forcing two arrays of unrelated data into a table structure defies its purpose. A possible alternative would be to use `Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled | Select Name,ObjectClass` and to use the `ObjectClass` column to identify the type of the disabled account in question.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a kind of strange request since you have two properties per line that are unrelated, but for simply academic purposes, this could be done with a `For` loop.

```
$RecordCount = if($ComputerDisabled.count -gt $UserDisabled.count){$ComputerDisabled.count}else{$UserDisabled.coun}
$AllDisabled = @()
For($i=0;$i -lt $RecordCount;$i++){
    $AllDisabled += [PSCustomObject]@{
        'ComputerDisabled' = $ComputerDisabled[$i].Name
        'UserDisabled' = $UserDisabled[$i].Name
    }
}
$AllDisabled | Export-CSV C:\Path\To\File.csv -notype
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me direction, let me solve my problems.
I follow your logic and script,  I got the output format.